# How to show more folder options when bookmarking pages in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I have a lot of folders in my chrome (e.g., Music, food, Novel, Movie).

I will add different types of pages to each corresponding folders. And the desired folder options will descend if I have chosen too many folders before.

In default, it shows only 8 folders to choose from. The last 3 folder options are fixed (pined) and the top 5 folder options are changeable.

I'm wondering if there's a way to show more folder options in the "Bookmark added" menu or even pin the folder options. So I don't need to click "choose another folder" button to choose folders I frequently used.

[image: The "Bookmark added" menu]

Comment: This is a security related site sir.

Comment: So sorry. I didn't notice about that. Thank you!